# Mat file loads slower than m-file

Tags: performance, matlab, load

I have a large variable stored in a mat file and in a .m file. 
The data is just a big cell:

```
Tensor{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}=[1,1,2,2,1, (... )];

Tensor{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2}=[1,1,2,2,3, (... )];

(...)
```

Why it is so much slower to load the variable form the mat-file, than from the m-file?

```
tic;load('Tensor.mat');toc
Elapsed time is 6.969654 seconds.

tic;Tensor;toc
Elapsed time is 0.152476 seconds.
```

Is there a way to save variables as m-files?

@Daniel An example of a typical entry is:

```
Tensor{2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4} = [ ...
    0,0,0,0,0,(1 / 6) .* 22 .^ (-1 / 2),0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ; ...
    0,0,0,0,(1 / 6) .* ( 5 / 33) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-1 / 12) .* (7 / 11) .^ (1 / 2),0,0,0,0,0,0 ; ...
    0,0,0, (1 / 11) .* (5 / 6) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-35 / 132) .* 3 .^ (-1 / 2),0,(7 / 44) .* 3 .^ (-1 / 2),0,0,0,0,0; ...
    0,0,(1 / 11) .* (5 / 6) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-7 / 33),0,(1 / 44) .* 105 .^ (1 / 2),0,(-7 / 66),0,0,0,0; ...
    0,(1 / 6) .* (5 / 33) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-7 / 33),0,(7 / 33) .* (5 / 2) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-35 / 198) .* (5 / 2) .^ (1 / 2),0,(7 / 66),0,0,0; ...
    (1 / 6) .* 22 .^ (-1 / 2),0,(-35 / 132) .* 3 .^ (-1 / 2),0,(7 / 33) .* (5 / 2) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-25 / 66) .* (7 / 6) .^ (1 / 2),0,(35 / 198) .* (5 / 2) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-7 / 44) .* 3 .^ (-1 / 2),0,0; ...
    0,(-1 / 12) .* (7 / 11) .^ (1 / 2),0,(1 / 44) .* 105 .^ (1 / 2),0,(-25 / 66) .* (7 / 6) .^ (1 / 2),0,(25 / 66) .* (7 / 6) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-1 / 44) .* 105 .^ (1 / 2),0,(1 / 12) .* (7 / 11) .^ (1 / 2),0; ...
    0,0,(7 / 44) .* 3 .^ (-1 / 2),0,(-35 / 198) .* (5 / 2) .^ (1 / 2) ,0,(25 / 66) .* (7 / 6) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-7 / 33) .* (5 / 2) .^ (1 / 2),0,( 35 / 132) .* 3 .^ (-1 / 2),0,(-1 / 6) .* 22 .^ (-1 / 2); ...
    0,0,0,(-7 / 66), 0,(35 / 198) .* (5 / 2) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-7 / 33) .* (5 / 2) .^ (1 / 2),0,( 7 / 33),0,(-1 / 6) .* (5 / 33) .^ (1 / 2),0; ...
    0,0,0,0,(7 / 66),0,(-1 / 44) .* 105 .^ (1 / 2),0,(7 / 33),0,(-1 / 11) .* (5 / 6) .^ (1 / 2),0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0,0,(-7 / 44) .* 3 .^ (-1 / 2),0,(35 / 132) .* 3 .^ (-1 / 2),0,(-1 / 11) .* (5 / 6) .^ (1 / 2),0,0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,(1 / 12) .* (7 / 11) .^ (1 / 2),0,(-1 / 6) .* (5 / 33) .^ (1 / 2),0,0,0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,(-1 / 6) .* 22 .^ (-1 / 2),0,0,0,0,0 ...
    ] ;
```

Comment: Careful with the tags! [tag:m] and [tag:mat] have nothing to do with Matlab; see their description

Comment: What version are the .mat files saved with? If they are more recent than 6 they are compressed and it might take more time to decompress them when you load them into the workspace. Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html) for infos. To check the version, write this in the Command Window: `type('YourMatFile.mat')`

Comment: The version is MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64. It does not chance if i try to save it as a different version e.g. with the -v7 command.

Comment: Are you loading the file over a network - or is the disk local?  (same question for `.m` file

Comment: They are both saved local.

Comment: @Fabian: Could you provide an example which allows us to reproduce the behaviour? There must be something special to your data.

Comment: Do you really need 12 dimensions for your cell array ? If all your values are numerical could you use a simple matrix ?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the .mat-file is a binary file that requires some processing to extract a variable, while the .m-file is nothing else just a text file. Instead of .m-file it is more convenient to save data in .dat-file. The result should be about the same. This can be checked trying these two commands:

```
tic;load('Tensor.mat');toc
tic;load('Tensor.dat','-ascii');toc
```